# I'm new to firebase, how do I change tables from an app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

my question is regarding firebase databases, I'm trying to make an app that will be able to create or manipulate any row/column/variable in a database,  how do I go about doing that? Do I treat every child as a row? Sorry if my question doesn't make sense, I'm new to all of this :)

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Realtime Database is a NoSQL database, so it doesn't have the concept of tables, rows and columns. Instead it's just a tree of values. To learn more about these types of databases, read [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), or watch [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

I recommend getting started with the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start) or with one of the many [Firebase database tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+database+tutorial) out there. The simplest example to writing to the database there is:

> ```
> // Write a message to the database
> FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
> DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
>
> myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
> ```

This writes a single value to a node named `message` in the database. If you want to write another message, you can do:

```
database.getReference("message2").setValue("Hello again!");
```

Or by adding a but more structure:

```
database.getReference("messages").push().setValue("Hello World!");
```

The last line creates a node called `messages` and  under that a new key with a random (but always incrementing) key and the value `"Hello World!"`. This `messages` is probably the closest equivalent to the table that you're looking for.

That's about as much as can fit in an answer, so check out the links I gave and just try something. Once you start writing code, it's actually quite easy to get the hang of.